# How can I programmatically clear cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cache-control

In my application (`ASP.NET` + `c#`) I need to clear the cache before a user enters an aspx page.

Does anybody have any idea how I can programmatically clear the cache on an aspx page, or in the code behind (c#)?

Comment: client cache, My code it's working only when I clear cache on the browser, otherwise not..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write following code in the page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
    Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Comment: it works for me but locally... when I publish my application to a server  it crashes again :(

Comment: What do mean by crashes again.Can u explain me little bit more what actually happened on server. Are u sure whatever crashes on server that's because of caching?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a page from the output cache as follows:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("MyPage.aspx");
```

This won't remove it from any client-side cache, so if you want to use this technique you will probably want to disable client-side cache, e.g. by using the following directive in your aspx page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="Server" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some javascript way to clear the cache (which would be awful), you can't.

Your best bet is to ensure the page doesn't get cached at all, by doing as Sukhi suggests - or setting up a no-cache cache profile and using the OutputCache directive.