# Load latest record and remove cache from particular page for Particular Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

**I have an Action method like below..**

```
[HttpGet, Route("All-Users"), OutputCache(Duration = 86400)]
public async Task<ActionResult> AllUsers()
{
    var list = await _user.GetUsersList();
    return View(list);
}
```

**I have another Action method that saves the User.**

Here the problem is that when I save the user..it still shows cache Page content. So this means newly added users are not appearing.

Kindly suggest how can i get rid of this issue.

**[I checked on Google that Cache can cleared as shown in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757733/how-can-i-programmatically-clear-cache)**

> Question: Will it clear cache for all pages or for above action method
>   only ?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Controller/AllUsers");`?

Comment: Will I remove Cache for particular Session or for all Sessions on the Server ?

Comment: At the moment, you only have a single item for all sessions anyway so yes it will.

Comment: Is it possible  to remove cache for particular Session only ?

Comment: Yes, but not for the action you have posted above.

Comment: To clarify, the action above will cache the value but it will be the same value for ALL users of your system.