# I have a html page that i load via aspx page. The html page has a link. I want the link to be unvisited

Tags: html, hyperlink

Once the link is visited I agree that the link turns purple. How do I retain it unvisited when I reload the HTML page?
Seems like the html page is cached and shows the link is visited. I have tried meta tags in html like:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The link still remains purple until I delete the temporary files via the internet options.
I dont want to do this manually everytime. Want to achieve it with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use css.

Style it however you want.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way related to caching? Thta i can avoid caching html pages?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I don't think its good practice. Is it really necessary? Here's a good reference though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757733/how-can-i-programmatically-clear-cache

Answer (score 0):

Do this with css using `:visited` selector.

> The :visited selector is used to select visited links.

<sub>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp</sub>

```css
a:not(.keep):visited {
  color:inherit;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#test">link</a>
<a href="#test" class="keep">This link will be pueple.</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the css solution. Is there any other way related to caching? Thta i can avoid caching html pages?

Comment: This is a totally different question but it seems that your tags should take care about this. As much as I know, the purple link not related to the cache but the history. Try to delete your history and check if it turn the color back.

Comment: Yes, thats what my question says. I didnt want it to do manually, the history deletion.

Comment: It was just for the test. If it related to the history, there is nothing you can do about it. But if you only want to affect on the style (which you can with `css`), why do you care about the history?

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know if there existed any way to deal with history."If it related to the history, there is nothing you can do about it." Got the answer.