# Is there a cache in .net (C#) that can be configured to be invalidated on a given times like crons ("0 30 8,17,23 ? * * *") formats?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, .net-framework-version

Hi everyone and thanks in advance,
I want to use a cache in .net C# that can be invalidated. But not at a given one time (15/12/2005 09:08:33) or sliding time (every 4 hours for example). What I want is the cache is refreshed for example every friday at 8:30, 17:30 and 19:45. Is there a cache class in c# that support it? just passing an optinal parameter in the cache object or something?

P.D.: netframework, not netcore.

I have been googling about the .net caches but I didnt found what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by invalidate the cache? If you want to clear the cache there are ways to do that, if you want to clear it every midnight there are also ways to do that, what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Hi @SupaMaggie70b , what I mean is refresh the cache in the way I am asking for (every friday at 8:30, 17:30 and 19:45, this is just an example).

Comment: No that I know of, you would be better off implementing that yourself. I would recommend using time.sleep or task.delay to wait until a time passes. To clear the cache, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757733/how-can-i-programmatically-clear-cache#4757786

Comment: @MiguelAngelHolgado  Refer [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a .NET type that has a scheduled clearing functionality, but you could just create a task that does it in the background on a weekly basis or on whichever schedule you prefer

Here I've created a task that takes a future date as a parameter and only clears the cache if the current date and time is greater than or equal to that date.

I've added a cancellation token so the task can be cancelled properly.

```
        readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public async Task CacheCleaner(DateTime nextCleanDate)
        {
            var targetDate = nextCleanDate;
            while (true)
            {
                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException();
                if(DateTime.Now >= targetDate)
                {
                   //clear your cache
                }
                targetDate = nextCleanDate.AddDays(7);
            }
        }
```